# Need to write 2 outer joins in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need to write the below query using linq. Any help is much appreciated.

```
select
        r1.rID,
        name,
        uName,
        001 aID,
        nvl(uValue, 0) uValue
    from
        r1,
        r2,
        l
    where
        r1.rID = r2.rID 
        and r1.rID = l.rID(+) 
        and 001 = l.aID(+)
    order by
        r1.rID
```

Comment: So do it or hire a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
var result = (from  r1 in db.r1
              join  r2 in db.r2 on r1.rID equals r2.rID
              join  l  in db.l  on r1.rID equals l.rID
              where l.aID == "001"
              orderby r1.rID 
              select new {
                  rID    = r1.rID,
                  Name   = r1.name,
                  UName  = r1.uName,
                  aID    = "001",
                  UValue = nvl(r.uValue)
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: The "(+)"s are Oracles way of saying "outer join".  They have no meaning in C#/LINQ